# Using Varnish only as a Reverse Proxy without caching

Tags: linux, reverse-proxy, varnish

I'd like to know what can I put in my VCL to tell Varnish to not cache the requests and pass all the requests to the backend, because I would like to use Varnish as a reverse proxy to hide the actual IP of my backends.
I did some researches but I didn't find anything concrete.
I'm using Varnish 3 and my actual Varnish VCl is:

```
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want varnish to do nothing with the request at all you should use pipe. This prevents varnish from rewriting the headers. The response is sent back from varnish directly.

```
sub vcl_recv {
    return(pipe);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to overwrite the default handling to force a 'pass'

This in both vcl_recv and vcl_fetch

> sub vcl_recv {
>       pass; }
>
> sub vcl_fetch {
>       pass; }

Comment: Hi, I added this to my devault.vcl but after a restart of Varnish I got this error :
"Message from VCC-compiler:
Please change "pass" to "return(pass)"."
So I changed "pass" to "return (pass);" and now I have this error :
"Invalid return "pass"
('input' Line 11 Pos 9)
return (pass);
--------####---


...in subroutine "vcl_fetch"
('input' Line 10 Pos 5)
sub vcl_fetch {
----#########---


...which is the "vcl_fetch" method
Legal returns are: "deliver" "error" "hit_for_pass" "restart"
Running VCC-compiler failed, exit 1"